# SPSS Correlate a Variable Sets with a Variable

Tags: statistics, spss, usage-statistics

I am doing a correlation studying.

I have a Multiple Response which can have more than a answer per case.

The multiple response (q06_*) is a question about the kinds of transport used. The case could have chosen more than one possibility.
[image: The multiple Response]

How is possible to make a *bivariate correlations* with this variable sets with an other variable (a score)?

Answer (score 0):

So, if I get this correctly then q06 is one item, and "U" to "Oth" are the means of transportation.
I am assuming you would like to make all of these (categorial data) variables into one (continuous) variable, so you can correlate it with another.

First of all, to just answer your question: You have to recode your q06_U to q06_oth into one variable like so (syntax):

```
if(q06_U=1)transportation=1.
if(q06_O=1)transportation=2.
...
execute.
```

This will create a new variable called "transportation", containing different means of transportation (for a start) at nominal scale of measurement (!!). 
One issue with this is, as you noted, you have to decide what to do with people who are using more than one mode of transportation. My above approach in creating the "transportation" variable puts people in different categories depending on the vehicle presented last in your list........

Long story short: To give you a helpful answer to your question it would be good to know what exactly you are researching. More precisely: Do you care more about which mode of transportation people used or how many in total or an exact combination of some.......and so on. Because at the end what correlation does is tell you to which extent a high value in variable one is associated with a high value in variable b. In my above example, from 1 to 2 is a huge difference (because two completely different means of transportation) whereas in IQ Scores the difference between 109 and 110 is of no relevance...

Not quite sure what exactly you need a hint on: statistics or spss syntax! I'm happy to help if I can :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What I need if I can find a correlation between the variable and each of the means of the variable b (q06_*). For that, I would like to have a table, which show the p value, the standard deviation and the means. Like the bivariate colleration test (Pearson) shows.

Comment: I see! So, your problem then is calculating a "mean score" for your q06_* variables, because means and standard deviations of categorial data don't really make sense. Again, to give you helpful answer I need to know which question you are trying to answer with your correlation. You could do a pearson correlation between each of your q06_* vars and your dv. Doing this your results would equal a t-test with q06_* var as group variable. Of course this gives you some kind of correlation between the variables - but interpretation of r changes of course compared to two continous variables.

Comment: The research question: there is a correlation between the perceived stress level and the time/frequency spent on public transport.
Now I want to found if I have other correlation between the PS score and other variables, in particular with the kind of transport

Comment: So all q06_* are public transport and you are just interested in the r(frequency / stress)?

Comment: Yes the relation between frequency with Strees. I also try to relate all the other variable with the stress, like kind of transport, gender, ecc..

Comment: Do then wouldn’t it be feasible to just sum all public transport positive answers and correlate them with the stress variable? still don‘t seem to get the problem. for further help please could you provide all variables and all options to answer

Comment: I think I should put it in a easier way, I am not sure if we are talking about the same thing. The relation between the stress with the kind of transport, means: r(train/stress) or (tram/stress), etc.. Test the correlation with any options (nominal variables) which are "train", "underground", "overground", "Bus".

Comment: Alright...so: If you didn't actually measure time (in a continuus numeric fashion) you can't test for that. As for the frequency or general relation to stress you have the following options: a) you make a variable that has "train+underground+overground+bus" and thus a continuus variable measuring in a very basic way to what extent someone uses public transport. If someone who never goes by car or bike but only uses the bus you will falsely assume this person to be not so public transport friendly. b) if the groups are > 20 or so use all your variables as group variable in a t test / manova